# Windows phone 8 and header with keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So I have a really huge problem:

On my page (It’s about the same as a "messages app" from Microsoft), when I click on my input box and keyboard pop up, my header is moved up and no longer visible.

I’ve searched a little and most of solutions I’ve found were not working (targeting wp7 for them...) . (Like a blog where guy creates a lot of dependency property for then margin of Phoneframe is changed. It works, a little, but the header goes off during animation of keyboard. It’s not enough, it’s really not perfect. )

The Microsoft manages it in standard “Messages” app (With a little bug of font size changing), so it must be possible.

How can  realize that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this solution and it works just fine :

1. Try to listen to the `TextBox.GotFocus` and `TextBox.LostFocus` events to detect when a TextBox in your application acquires and looses focus.
2. Put your whole content in a `ScrollViewer` just as follows :

**Code XAML :**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid  Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="254" Margin="10,183,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

1. Adding the content in a ScrollViewer will give the experience of scrolling even when the keyboard is not open, and that's not really desirable.
   For that you need to disable scrolling before the Keyboard is opened and after the keyboard is closed.
2. In the TextBox_GotFocus event play on the top margin of the ScrollViewer :

in the constructor :

```
public MainPage()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            LayoutRoot.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
}
```

**the events :**

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 330, 0, 0);
     LayoutRoot.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
}
```

Add the TextBox_LostFocus event handler also to get the page back to its original view when the keyboard is closed :

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
      LayoutRoot.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
}
```

This helps you get the page to its somehow original position when the keyboard is opened.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the UI as listbox so that you can scroll the listbox and check the header which is gone up.

Answer (score -1):

When SIP keyboard is rendered, PhoneApplicationFrame.TranslateTransform.Y is set to specific values (-259 in landscape orientation, -339 in portrait orientation). To update layout, we’ll just set top margin to the specified value(-s) and after that Silverlight layout system will fix the issue.

here XAML part:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="WINDOWS PHONE" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="developer's ?" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus"/>
    </Grid>
```

C# portions

```
    private const double LandscapeShift = -259d;
    private const double LandscapeShiftWithBar = -328d;
    private const double Epsilon = 0.00000001d;
    private const double PortraitShift = -339d;
    private const double PortraitShiftWithBar = -408d;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TranslateYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TranslateY", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnRenderXPropertyChanged));

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPageLoaded;
    }

    public double TranslateY
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(TranslateYProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TranslateYProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnRenderXPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainPage)d).UpdateTopMargin((double)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindToKeyboardFocus();
    }

    private void BindToKeyboardFocus()
    {
        PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        if (frame != null)
        {
            var group = frame.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
            if (group != null)
            {
                var translate = group.Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
                var translateYBinding = new Binding("Y");
                translateYBinding.Source = translate;
                SetBinding(TranslateYProperty, translateYBinding);     
            }
        }
    }     
    private void UpdateTopMargin(double translateY)
    {    
      if(IsClose(translateY, LandscapeShift) || IsClose(translateY,PortraitShift) || IsClose(translateY, LandscapeShiftWithBar) || IsClose(translateY, PortraitShiftWithBar))
      {
        LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, -translateY, 0, 0);  
      }
    }

    private bool IsClose(double a, double b)
    {
        return Math.Abs(a - b) < Epsilon;
    }

    private void TextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness();
    }
```

You can try following link. I think it will be helpful.

http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/